# Is modifying our MAC Address a perfectly reversible operation?

Tags: home-networking, ip, mac-address

Ok guys I've just read this page: http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/changemac

But before I want to attempt anything, I want to ask: Is modifying our MAC Address (in the way provided at that page) a perfectly reversible operation?

plus there's no way anyone can track if you have ever changed your MAC Address?

Btw i'm using 32-bit Windows Vista sp2 Home Premium

Comment: @downvoter explain the downvotes if you can

Comment: I'm not one of the down voters, however I would image it is with regards to the intended usage. There are very few legitimate uses for MAC spoofing and people don't want to support something that could be used for nefarious purposes I'd image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With regards to tracking if a MAC has ever been changed you should understand that changing the MAC on a computer doesn't overwrite your current MAC address, it merely over-rides it. The network card has a burnt-in MAC address that can't be overwritten, so if you were to reinstall windows after a MAC address change you would go back to the old MAC address.

Answer (score 2):

If you can change it, you can change it back yes. I guess its possible to track if you are logged in under a domain account and then you change your MAC address. That could be something that is logged. Other than that though, not really possible.